# Emailing target csv file using post-session success emailing process in Informatica

Tags: email, csv, informatica

My Informatica mapping has 2 targets one of which is database which gets data upon insert and other one is csv file which is getting created and filled when there is an update.

This mapping runs daily and at the end of the workflow run if there is any csv file generated (it means there is some data which is updated), it should email that file.

Is there way I can do it ? If so, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Doesn't a 0 byte file gets generated even when there is no updates?

Comment: It has headers included in it. So that will still remain in it. But what has that to do with the emailing part. My concern is how to send an attachment using informatica, only when the csv file is populated. Tried using command task,  but can't use "tgtsuccessrows">0 because it will send it even when there rows are inserted into other target(database) table